# How to fold a commit into the following commit with a git interactive rebase

Tags: git

In chronological order I have the following commits:

```
commit1
commit2
commit3
commit4
```

I would like to fold the `commit1` and `commit2` into `commit3` discarding their messages.

I see that with `fixup` I can fold a newer commit in to an earlier commit, but I would like to fold older commits into newer commits...

Can somebody outline the required workflow so I can avoid making a mess of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the final change, merging the second one into the first is the same as merging the first into the second. The only difference is the message.

In the interactive rebase editor (from `git rebase -i`), mark `commit2` and `commit3` as `squash` to squash them into `commit1`, then when it offers you the chance to edit the commit message, delete the first two bits.